# Story about a government-imposed copyright law on all music, which backfires when it becomes impossible to create good, original music

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A cautionary tale of the "if this goes on..." ilk. The government, which includes all humanity, sets down a law that copyright and royalties apply to any musical theme, and with the aid of computers, manages to keep track of them. Although at first this is seen as a boon to composers, as the centuries pass, it becomes a burden as good, original music becomes impossible to create. For example, one composer who thinks he has created a delightful tune discovers, to his pain, that it is a recreation of a popular piece some decades earlier. Eventually, the law is overturned and the databases erased in order to give humanity the freedom to create again.

The story was in the English language, and included in an anthology, perhaps in the 70s to 90s, though I can't be certain of this.

Comment: This one? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205339/short-story-about-perils-of-indefinite-copyright

Comment: Sounds similar to *Melancholy Elephants* by Spider Robinson.

Comment: Thanks to you both, but no, this is a different story on a similar topic. I have read quite a few of Spider Robinson's stories, though.

Comment: How meta... If it's not *Melancholy Elephants* and not plagiarized, it's a strikingly fitting case of a very close story created by accident, down to the bit about the composer being crushed by the melody not being new.

Comment: What I remember, or seem to remember, is a story in which a database of copyrighted was created and was used for some centuries, I think in an interstellar context. _Melancholy Elephants_ describes a database being quashed before it got started. It disturbs me that I know I read _Melancholy Elephants_ when it was fresh (probably in 1985), and didn't think of it while writing the question. But I'd rather leave the question open a while longer before closing the case.

Comment: In "Melencholy Elephants", there already was a database, and with so many people, it was already causing problems. The question was just whether to quash a bill extending copyright to *perpetuity*. Mrs. Martin recounts to the senator, "The next day he submitted it for clearance, and learned that it had been a popular air during his early childhood, and had already been unsuccessfully submitted fourteen times since its original registration." It also was not just about Earth: "Senator, that bill is a short-term boon, to some artists--and a long-term disaster for all artists, on Earth and off."

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron The bit about the composer who unwittingly recreates a tune from 40 years earlier is straight out of "Melancholy Elephants."  I think you have to accept that's what you're remembering.  (And, in "Melancholy Elephants" the database _does_ already exist, what is at stake is perpetual copyright.)

Comment: I read a story around 1966, dealing with musical copyright issues.  Likely in Galaxy or If.  Something about composers not being able to afford the computer search costs (OK, the author got that one wrong!)  I thought it was an interesting subject.  But I can't remember the title, too long ago.  Try searching all stories in Galaxy or If for 65 or 66; best I can do.

Answer (score 6):

Having re-read the story, I'm convinced that you're simply misremembering Spider Robinson's "[Melancholy Elephants](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49479)."

The conflict is over a bill intended to grant *perpetual* copyright:

> "You know the system we have now, unchanged since the mid twentieth-century. Copyright ceases to exist fifty years after the death of the copyright holder. But the size of the human race has increased drastically since the 1900s—and so has the average human lifespan. Most people in developed nations now expect to live to be a hundred and twenty; you yourself are considerably older. And so, naturally, S. '896
> now seeks to extend copyright into perpetuity."

But every existing song is already tracked and protected, with the result is it has become increasingly hard to find new songs to compose:

> "Did you know that at present two out of every five copyright submissions to the Music Division are rejected on the first computer search?"
>
> The old man's face had stopped registering surprise, other than for histrionic purposes, more than a century before; nonetheless, she knew she had rocked him. "No, I did not."
>
> "Why would you know? Who would talk about it? But it is a fact nonetheless. Another fact is that, when the increase in number of working composers is taken into account, the rare of submissions to the Copyright Office is decreasing significantly. There are more composers than ever, but their individual productivity is declining.

The detail of the composer who is crushed to find out that the tune he wrote is one from years earlier is straight out of the story:

> "My husband wrote a song for me, on the occasion of our fortieth wedding anniversary. It was our love in music, unique and special and intimate, the most beautiful melody I ever heard in my life. It made him so happy to have written it. Of his last ten compositions he had burned five for being derivative, and the others had all failed of copyright clearance. But this was fresh, special—he joked that my love for him had inspired him. The next day he submitted it for clearance, and learned that it had been a popular air during his early childhood, and had already been unsuccessfully submitted fourteen times since its original registration. A week later he burned all his manuscripts and working tapes and killed himself."

The databases aren't burned immediately, but for the time being perpetual copyright is avoided, and there's hope that maybe that forgetting will be permitted:

> "If you live long enough," the senator said slowly at last, "there is nothing new under the sun." He shifted in his great chair. "If you're lucky, you die sooner than that. I haven't heard a new dirty joke in fifty years." He seemed to sit up straight in his chair. "I will kill S. 4217896."

It was collected in the Robinson collection [*Melancholy Elephants*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?29610) (1984) and the Asimov/Greenberg anthology [*The New Hugo Winners*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?33523) (1989).

Comment: I sure dislike the "Nothing new under the sun" concept because this is exactly what unoriginal comics (for example) assert in justifying their own plagiarism -- or they argue that their tweak to a joke makes it different even if it does not and the plagiarist, perhaps not being the brightest person, may literally not even get the idea of originality: if a plagiarist hears a joke and does its opposite, he may be so dim that he fails to see that a joke and its opposite are deeply related.